# Kettle: ETL Normalization split string fields

Tags: normalization, etl, kettle, geokettle

I have database where it has one attribute that actually carries two(string separated by "; "). Take a look on the following example:

**Example**

This is my Database A (Source) which has a table like this:

[image]

In fact, this seems all ok, but when you assume that the `author` can have one or more entrance. you will have a record like this:

document (**id** 1, **author** "John Matt; Mary Knight", **abstract** "Lorem ipsum...", **year** 2015)

So what i intend to do on Database B(Target) is something like this:
[image]

where `a_id` from table `Authors` is a foreign key that references `author_id` on table `Document`.

In first place ensure that i will fill all the authors (which there's no problem with that) and then assign the group authors to the respective document(which is the problem) because i can have this situation

Authors (**id** 1, **name** "John Matt")
        (**id** 2, **name** "John Matt")
        (**id** 2, **name** "Mary Knight")

Notice that the **id 2** will be the one to be inserted attending to the previous example.

**Question:**

How this procedure can be done using a ETL process using kettle?
Is this a good pratice or a string attribute separated by "; " it's good enough?

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly, you have a database having rows like

`document (id 1, author "John Matt; Mary Knight", abstract "Lorem ipsum...", year 2015)`

Now you need to extract the multiple authors which are separated by `;`.

PDI provides you with a step called **Split fields to row**. Use the separator as `;` and you will get multiple split copy of the data. Next you can then use an unique id from the author table.

Alternatively, you can use Modified Java Script step to split the rows also. Recommend you to use the first step.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I already did what you have suggested. The main problem is how can i get the unique id from the groupauthor table and put it back in the document table of Database B (Target) instead of the string  "John Matt; Mary Knight".